# Error while evaluating JSX element in React Native

Tags: react-native, babeljs, reactjs, jsx

When running my app I get into an error while the babel compiler is processing the JSX. It could be due to misconfiguration in the `.babelrc`. Here is the error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react.React.createElement')

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8n0h.png)

- Adding `transform-react-jsx` plugin for babel doesn't solve the problem

index.js:

```
renderLoadingView() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>  // Failing on index.js:217
      <Text>
        Loading the app...
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native-stage-0"]
}
```

Comment: Could it be because you forgot to `import React from 'react'` in your file? JSX is not an issue, it seems; the issue is that `React.createElement` is undefined, the most likely cause of which is not importing it

Comment: At the first look it seems that it is being imported. The line that imports React in my `index.js` is as follows `import { React, Component } from 'react';`

Comment: It should be `import React, { Component } from 'react'`

Comment: Yes, you are right. It solved my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import React if you use JSX, so you need to write

```
import React from 'react';
```

at the top of your file.